# Refer data from sheet2 to sheet1 dynamically based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sheet1 and sheet2.
Sheet1 has "today()" and "today()+1" as B2 and C2 respectively. B3 and C3 have some numerical values referenced from sheet2.
Sheet2 has B column as list of dates and C column has list of values.
Values of Sheet2 has to be reflected in sheet1 only for the dates of "today()" and "today+1". May I know, how can we apply it?

I tried to apply by referencing cells. But, I am unable to reference based on the date columns dynamically.

[image: Sheet]
[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$13,2,False)`
Try this formula in B3 and C3 of sheet1. Change B2 in the formula to C2 for C3 cell.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. one question. What does the parameter '2' before 'False' represent?

Comment: It represents the column number in the data range. We have two columns named B and C in the range. It says, take the C column value where the date matches the value in B.